# Split row into multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table:

```
+---------+------+---------+
|  Col1   | Col2 |  Col3   |
+---------+------+---------+
| PersonA | $10  | PersonB |
| PersonC | $20  | PersonD |
+---------+------+---------+
```

I want result like this:

```
+---------+-----+-----+
|  Col1   | Db  | Cr  |
+---------+-----+-----+
| PersonA | 0   | $10 |
| PersonB | $10 | 0   |
| PersonC | 0   | $20 |
| PersonD | $20 | 0   |
+---------+-----+-----+
```

Is there any way without using `Union all`?

Comment: What is the dbms?

Comment: Why not `UNION ALL`? Seems like the right tool here...

Comment: since there are million record, Union All will read same table again. So i was thinking if there is any way which is without union all.
DBMS is mssql

Comment: What's wrong with reading the same table again? I don't really understand your concern?

Answer (score 4):

If col1 stands for CR and col3 for DB, you can use UNION ALL as below to get your desired output-

```
SELECT col1 PersonName, 
'$0' DB,
col2 CR    
FROM your_table

UNION ALL

SELECT col3 PersonName,
col2 DB, 
'$0' CR    
FROM your_table
```

To keep the transaction order as original, you need to create ROW_NUMBER first and then order by RN. ROW_NUMBER creation is different in different database. As you did not mention the database name, I can not add that logic here.

As you are looking for avoiding UNION ALL, you can think about UNPIVOT as below if you are using MSSQL-

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT U.PersonName,
    CASE WHEN U.name = 'Col3' THEN U.Col2 ELSE '$0' END AS Db,
    CASE WHEN U.name = 'Col1' THEN U.Col2 ELSE '$0' END AS Cr,
    U.name ValuesFromColumn -- Just print this for better understanding
    FROM your_table S
    UNPIVOT
    (
        PersonName
        FOR NAME IN (col1,col3)
    ) U
)

-- Now select from CTE and Join other table as

SELECT * 
FROM CTE A
LEFT JOIN Other_Table B ON....

-- OR Like

SELECT * 
FROM Other_Table A
LEFT JOIN CTE B ON....
```

UNPIVOT is also available in other databases. You can adjust Syntax accordingly if you are using other database.

Comment: since there are million records, Union All will read same table again. So i was thinking if there is any way which is without union all

Comment: What is your database?

Comment: one question, can i do left join of this output result with other table? This result should be on right side of the Left Join. Lets say i want Person ID which is in other table , Select PersonID, Person Name, Db, Cr from PersonMaster Left join [your_table S]

Comment: Sure, just keep full inside CTE and JOIN anything with the CTE.

Comment: i tried with left join, but may be i am going wrong and not getting it. I want table x to be Left joined with result of unpivot. For e.g Table X will have all the personal ID and Name, unpivot will have name, so List all person in table x and left join with unpivot result (select .....from tableX left join unpivotresult on x.name = unpivot.name)

Answer (score 2):

You may achieve this by using `unpivot` in MSSQL, since you want to convert your **column into rows**. Please find this link for more info about unpivot in SQL.[UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017).

An `UNPIVOT` with `case` is sufficient to get your result.

```
declare @tab table ( cola varchar(50), colb int, colc varchar(50))

insert into @tab ( cola, colb, colc )
values ( 'A', 10, 'B')
, ( 'C', 20, 'D' )

select name,
case when colname = 'colc' then colb else '0' end as debit,
case when colname = 'cola' then colb else '0' end as credit
FROM @tab S
UNPIVOT
(
    name
    FOR colname  IN (cola,colc)
) U;
```

Comment: one question, can i do left join of this output result with other table? This result should be on right side of the Left Join. Lets say i want  Person ID which is in other table , Select PersonID, Person Name, debit,credit from PersonMaster Left join (your above @tab)

Answer (score 0):

Use `apply`:

```
select v.*
from t cross apply
     (values (t.col1, t.col2, 0),
             (t.col3, 0, t.col2)
     ) v(col1, db, cr);
```

Lateral joins (what `apply` implements) are very powerful.  In this case, it should be the most concise and best performing method for this problem.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3317cd169a32b03eb9f4280fc1c03586) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

You can continue to add joins or `apply`:

```
select v.*
from t cross apply
     (values (t.col1, t.col2, 0),
             (t.col3, 0, t.col2)
     ) v(col1, db, cr) left join
     x
     on x.? = v.?;
```

Comment: This works, but one question: how do i use this output with LEFT Join? v.col1 needs to be left join with other table.

Comment: @user1041627 . . . Just add `left join x on x.? = v.?`.

Comment: not working, your query it says " from t cross apply" so i can take only " t left join x on t.? = x.?   ////// it does not allow v to be bound with table t

Comment: Can i use table X on left side? Take everythng from table X and match with Table V......Select x.name, v.db, v.cr from X  left join  V on x.name = v.col1 (v is cross apply result)

Comment: @user1041627 . . . It is just like any other derived table or table reference in the `FROM` clause.