# Unpivot, Left Join and Sum

Tags: sql, sql-server

Following is the table structure and query i am running.
It does not throw the correct sum.

```
declare @tabM table (customerid int, Ledgerid int, customername varchar(50))
declare @tabA table (customerid int, amount int, Tocustomerid int)
declare @tabB table (customerid int, amount int,receiptid int)
declare @tabc table (Ledgerid int, amount int, serviceid int)

insert into @tabM (customerid, ledgerid, customername)
values (1,101,'AAA'),(2,102,'BBB'),(3,103,'CCC'),(4,104,'DDD'),(5,105,'EEE')

insert into @tabA (customerid, amount, Tocustomerid)
values (1,500,10),(2,300,5),(4,900,2),(5,100,1)

insert into @tabB (customerid, amount, receiptid)
values (3,300,99),(1,1680,13),(5,420,16),(1,150,110)

-- below is select Query with Unpivot and Left join

select m.customerid,m.customername, sum(b.amount)
from @TabM M 
left join @TabA A
unpivot
(
Ucustomerid
for colname in (customerid,ToCustomerID)
) U 
on m.customerid = u.Ucustomerid

left join @tabB B on m.customerid = b.customerID
group by m.customerid, m.customername
```

Result gives me sum for the

customerid 1 = 3660

customerid 5 = 840

**it is doubling the values,
correct answer should be**

customerid 1 = 1830

customerid 5 = 420

---

**Update:---**
**following is what i have and what i want.**

---

**TableM**

```
+------------+---------+--------------+
| CustomerID | LegerID | CustomerName |
+------------+---------+--------------+
|          1 |     101 | AAA          |
|          2 |     102 | BBB          |
|          3 |     103 | CCC          |
|          4 |     104 | DDD          |
|          5 |     105 | EEE          |
+------------+---------+--------------+
```

---

**TableA**

```
+----------------+--------+--------------+
| FromCustomerID | amount | ToCustomerID |
+----------------+--------+--------------+
|              1 | $500   |           10 |
|              2 | $300   |            5 |
|              3 | $900   |            2 |
|              5 | $100   |            1 |
+----------------+--------+--------------+
```

---

**TableB**

```
+------------+--------+
| CustomerID | amount |
+------------+--------+
|          3 | $400   |
|          1 | $1,680 |
|          5 | $420   |
|          1 | $150   |
+------------+--------+
```

***I want result like this***

```
╔════════════╦══════════════╦═════════╦═══════════════════════════════════╗
║ CustomerID ║ CustomerName ║ Amount  ║ Calculation = (TableA) + Table(B) ║
╠════════════╬══════════════╬═════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╣
║          1 ║ AAA          ║ $2,430  ║ ($500+$100)+($1680+$150)          ║
║          2 ║ BBB          ║ $1,200  ║ ($300+$900)+($0)                  ║
║          3 ║ CCC          ║ $1,300  ║ ($900)+($400)                     ║
║          4 ║ DDD          ║ $0      ║ $0 + $0                           ║
║          5 ║ EEE          ║ $820    ║ ($300+$100)+($420)                ║
╚════════════╩══════════════╩═════════╩═══════════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Sample data in a *text table* format and an explanation of the logic would help.  Non-working code does not necessarily provide much information.

Comment: i updated my question

Comment: TableA says `FromCustomerID`. You are take the `amount` and add it? But the money is going to some other Customer ID, yes?  For example, CustomerID 1 sends $500 to CustomerID 10. That does not mean CustomerID 1 has $500... CustomerID 10 now has $500.

Comment: yes, but I need total transaction amount done by PersonA, does not matter if he received or sent. Just make total for all the transaction PersonA made

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're using `UNPIVOT` at all. Just some `LEFT JOIN`s gets you the results you appear to be after:

```
SELECT M.customerid,
       M.customername,
       --SUM(B.amount)
       SUM(B.amount) AS amount
FROM @tabM M
     LEFT JOIN @tabA A ON M.customerid = A.customerid
     LEFT JOIN @tabB B ON A.customerid = B.customerid
GROUP BY M.customerid,
       M.customername;
```

Comment: if you see, TabB has two columns both containing customer id (b.customerid and to.customerID) and i need to split them. That is why i am using unpivot

Comment: But as soon as your `JOIN` is on `A.customerid` OR `A.Tocustomerid`you  get the wrong results. The above gets the right results. i think we need you to explain your logic, and problem more examples (and don't return `NULL`)

Comment: PersonA    $100    PersonB,  I need to consider that $100 for both person (A & B), my tableB has Two Columns with customerID, and Amount column is common between them. I need to have PersonA = $100, PersonB=$100

Comment: As I said, @user1041627 "*i think we need you to explain your logic, and problem more examples "* Without an explaination *in your question* and the full result set, we have no chance of helping you here other than guessing.

Comment: i do not know what more to explain, check this link why i need to use unpivot. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57439167/split-row-into-multiple-rows

Comment: You haven't explained anything in your question though, @user1041627. Some SQL, and the wrong results , and then incomplete correct results isn't an explainantion. We don't know your data, or your goals; you have to explain your needs as if you are explaining it to a completely stranger, with no knowledge of your system, data, or requirements. Why? Because that is exactly what we are.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed ToCustomerID in colname. If you add it sum 2 times

```
SELECT m.customerid,m.customername, SUM(b.amount)
    FROM #TabM M 
    LEFT JOIN #TabA A
    UNPIVOT
    (
        Ucustomerid FOR colname IN (customerid )
    ) U 
    ON m.customerid = u.Ucustomerid
    LEFT JOIN #tabB B ON m.customerid = b.customerID
    GROUP BY m.customerid, m.customername
```

Comment: But i need to have Tocustomer id. It is must because i want to calculate same amount for "TocustomerID"

Answer (score 0):

i think your answer should be like this...

```
declare @tabM table (customerid int, Ledgerid int, customername varchar(50))
declare @tabA table (customerid int, amount int, Tocustomerid int)
declare @tabB table (customerid int, amount int,receiptid int)
declare @tabc table (Ledgerid int, amount int, serviceid int)

insert into @tabM (customerid, ledgerid, customername)
values (1,101,'AAA'),(2,102,'BBB'),(3,103,'CCC'),(4,104,'DDD'),(5,105,'EEE')

insert into @tabA (customerid, amount, Tocustomerid)
values (1,500,10),(2,300,5),(4,900,2),(5,100,1)

insert into @tabB (customerid, amount, receiptid)
values (3,300,99),(1,1680,13),(5,420,16),(1,150,110)



select m.customerid,m.customername, sum(b.amount) as Total from @tabM m
left join @tabA a 
on m.customerid=a.customerid
left Join @tabB b
on m.customerid=b.customerid
group by m.customerid,m.customername
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: no, this is not correct result what i wanted. Your query does not refer to "ToCustomerID" in TableA. See my updated question for more understanding

Answer (score 0):

Some of you vale are getting doubled because in table B you have multiple entry for a same customer. You need to calculate table wise SUM of each customer first before establishing the JOINS. You can check this below script-

```
declare @tabM table (customerid int, Ledgerid int, customername varchar(50))
declare @tabA table (customerid int, amount int, Tocustomerid int)
declare @tabB table (customerid int, amount int,receiptid int)
declare @tabc table (Ledgerid int, amount int, serviceid int)

insert into @tabM (customerid, ledgerid, customername)
values (1,101,'AAA'),(2,102,'BBB'),(3,103,'CCC'),(4,104,'DDD'),(5,105,'EEE')

insert into @tabA (customerid, amount, Tocustomerid)
values (1,500,10),(2,300,5),(3,900,2),(5,100,1)

insert into @tabB (customerid, amount, receiptid)
values (3,400,99),(1,1680,13),(5,420,16),(1,150,110)



SELECT M.customerid, M.customername,
SUM(COALESCE(A1.amount,0))+SUM(COALESCE(A2.amount,0))+SUM(COALESCE(B.amount,0)) Amount
FROM @tabM M
LEFT JOIN (SELECT CustomerID, SUM(amount) amount FROM @tabA GROUP BY  CustomerID) A1 ON M.customerid = A1.customerid
LEFT JOIN (SELECT toCustomerID, SUM(amount) amount FROM @tabA GROUP BY  toCustomerID) A2 ON M.customerid = A2.tocustomerid
LEFT JOIN (SELECT CustomerID, SUM(amount) amount FROM @tabB GROUP BY  CustomerID) B ON M.customerid = B.customerid
GROUP BY M.customerid, M.customername
```

Alternative option is to UNION ALL records from different table and then apply GROUP BY to get your desired results as below-

```
SELECT M.customerid,M.customername,COALESCE(B.Amount,0) Amount 
FROM @tabM M
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT customerid,SUM(amount)  Amount
    FROM
    (
        SELECT customerid,amount FROM @tabA
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Tocustomerid,amount FROM @tabA
        UNION ALL
        SELECT customerid,amount FROM @tabB
    )A
    GROUP BY customerid
)B ON M.customerid = B.customerid
```

Output is-

```
customerid  customername    Amount
1           AAA             2430
2           BBB             1200
3           CCC             1300
4           DDD             0
5           EEE             820
```

Comment: yeah, this one works. I did try same before, but dropped idea to have joins with select query. Left Join (Select.....) was having high cost compare to Left Join (tablename). I have millions record in each 3 tables, so i was wondering if i find some way without using "select" statement after each left join. I agree with your logic but expoloring possiblities having less cost.

Comment: @user1041627 please check alternative option I have added in the answer. Not sure performance wise this will be better or not but I found these are the only 2 option for getting your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for you:

```
select m.CustomerID, m.CustomerName, m.total2 + isnull(sum(a2.amount), 0.0) as total3
from
(
select m.CustomerID, m.CustomerName, m.total1 + isnull(sum(a1.amount), 0.0) as total2
from
(
select m.CustomerID, m.CustomerName, isnull(sum(b.amount), 0.0) as total1
from TableM m
left join TableB b on m.CustomerID = b.CustomerID
group by m.CustomerID, m.CustomerName
) as m
left join TableA a1 on m.CustomerID = a1.FromCustomerID
group by m.CustomerID, m.CustomerName, m.total1
) as m
left join TableA a2 on m.CustomerID = a2.ToCustomerID
group by m.CustomerID, m.CustomerName, m.total2
```